# About Android In-app billing RESTORE_TRANSACTION for Subscriptions

Tags: android, in-app-billing, restore, subscription

In the following cases, how can I get any response ?

I purchased [one month subscription] in September 15, 2013.
I cancelled this subscription in the middle of the month. (For example, September 25, 2013)
Again, I purchased [one month subscription] in November 20, 2013.

Now(November 27, 2013), if I call RESTORE_TRANSACTION, how can I get any response ?
Purchase information of November and September? Or purchase information only in November?

Purpose of My App is, 
In order to restore the items available in the Subscription period was in effect, I want to get the purchase history of all past.

Because I am developing an app, I can not reproduce this situation.

How to restore is a general method as follows, such as written in the development document.

```
Bundle request = makeRequestBundle("RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS");
request.putLong(REQUEST_NONCE, mNonce);
Bundle response = mService.sendBillingRequest(request);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The purpose of the question, I want to get all the purchase history of the past. If I cant, I'm thinking that there is a need to manage the purchase history of the past, such as a database.

Comment: Edit your question to include the purpose for clarification. Also include the things you tried already + code.